Do I need to publish facebook app in order to put my react native app that uses facebook sign in into production?
I created react-native application for both iOS and Android using react-native-fbsdk-next.
It is purely used for sign in and it is working fine on both platform.
I'm about to publish the app into production but I'm not sure if I should publish facebook app that I created to sign in to my react native application since it is a bit hastle.

Generally For that we have to make your Facebook Developer account to set as Live/Production, currently it is in development mode apart from that nothing else to do :)
PS: For doing your account set to production you need to verify your business profile.
